# eclipse e4 - How are eclipse e4 views (parts) uniquely identified?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am using PartDescriptors to create multiple instances of the same `MPart`.
How do I identify each part ? I eclipse rcp 3.x it is easy to find a `ViewPart` by its primary and Seconday id. How do I achieve this in e4 rcp programming model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the parts created from the descriptor will have the same id so it is up to you to add some additional identifying information.

One way to do this is to add your own unique data to the part's transient data when you create the part:

```java
Object uniqueId = .....

part.getTransientData().put("part id key", uniqueId);
```

And read the id with:

```java
part.getTransientData().get("part id key");
```

To find the part you can use one of the `findElements` methods of `EModelService`. The version with a `Selector` lets you code a match on the id and the data. For example if everything is in one part stack:

```java
MPartStack partStack = .... get part stack

List<MPart> parts = modelService.findElements(partStack, MPart.class, EModelService.ANYWHERE, new FindPartSelector(id, data));
```

where `FindPartSelector` is a selector you write. This just has one method:

```java
@Override
public boolean select(final MApplicationElement element)
{
  // TODO match id and transient data
}
```

Note that the transient data is lost when you exit your RCP. If these parts are being persisted between sessions you can use `getPersistedState` rather than `getTransientData`.

Comment: ok I will always have to iterate through all the parts got through `partService.getParts()` and then find my part . is that right ?

Comment: You can use one of the `EModelService` `findElements` methods to do the search - see updated answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that when the workbench model is persisted (-clearPersistedData param not set), the transient data is dropped. Now, if the workbench model is restored on the next launch, the parts will not have that "secondary ID".